# How to iterate an array of objects and print out one of its properties

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, jslink

I have the following code in a display template in sharepoint, I have an array of objects and I need to have the following result.

```
Name1
Name2
Name3
```

So I can replace the default rendering of sharepoint multiple people user field with a tooltip.

However, I dont know how to iterate and then concatenate:

Screenshot:
[image]

Code:

```
// List View - Substring Long String Sample 
// Muawiyah Shannak , @MuShannak 

(function () { 

    // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render  
    var projectTeamContext = {}; 
    projectTeamContext.Templates = {}; 
    projectTeamContext.Templates.Fields = { 
        // Apply the new rendering for Body field on list view 
        "Project_x0020_Team": { "View": ProjectTeamTemplate } 
    }; 

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(projectTeamContext); 

})(); 

// This function provides the rendering logic 
function ProjectTeamTemplate(ctx) { 

    var projectTeamValue = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name]; 

    //newBodyvalue should have the list of all display names and it will be rendered as a tooltip automaticlaly

    return "<span title='" + projectTeamValue + "'>" + newBodyValue + "</span>"; 

}
```

Comment: its automatically populated by Sharepoint. if you see the screenshot you will see its an array of objects with some properties, i am only interested in the Names properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "map" property values from the `projectTeamValue` array objects into a new array, then "join" those values together (using ", " as the separator in this example) all in one go:

```
var newBodyValue = projectTeamValue.map(function(person) {
    return person.value;
}).join(", ");
```

If your `projectTeamValue` array looked like:

```
[{ value: "Name1" }, { value: "Name2" }, { value: "Name3" }]
```

Then `newBodyValue` would be:

```
"Name1, Name2, Name3"
```

- [**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/y914x5nv/)

Side note: [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) was not available in IE 8 and below but should work in every other browser.